# How to set "#bytes in next field" field?

Tags: transactions

The parameter field was added when I initiated transcation and now I understand from tezos developer docs that I need to populate the following data formats.

```
fitness.elem
************

+-----------------------+----------+-------------------------+
| Name                  | Size     | Contents                |
+=======================+==========+=========================+
| # bytes in next field | 4 bytes  | unsigned 30-bit integer |
+-----------------------+----------+-------------------------+
| Unnamed field 0       | Variable | bytes                   |
+-----------------------+----------+-------------------------+
```

What is "# bytes in next field"? How do I get it?